# How to write custom pipe-friendly functions?

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm trying to create [pipe-friendly functions](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/07/writing-pipe-friendly-functions/) using `magrittr`

For example, I tried to write a custom function to calculate the mean of a column:

```
library(magrittr)
custom_function <-
  function(.data, x) {
   mean(.data$x)
  }

mtcars %>%
 custom_function(mpg)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'mpg' not found
```

Maybe my reference to the variable is not working. How do I fix this `.data$x` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, we can change the `$` to `[[` and convert the unquoted column names to `character` with `deparse/substitute`

```
custom_function <- function(.data, x) {
  mean(.data[[deparse(substitute(x))]])
 }
```

Now, we apply the function

```
mtcars %>%
  custom_function(mpg)
#[1] 20.09062
```

The issue with `$` is that it is literally checking the column name 'x' without the associative value it stored.  Thus, it is failing and returns `NULL`

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use the curly-curly operator (`{{}}`) to do the evaluation within `summarise`.  As we need only a single summarised output, `summarise` can return that single value whereas if we need to create a new column in the original dataset, we need `mutate`.  After we create summarised column, just `pull` that column as a `vector`

```
custom_function <- function(.data, x) {
     .data %>%
         summarise(out = mean({{x}})) %>%
         pull(out)
}

mtcars %>% 
   custom_function(mpg)
[1] 20.09062
```

Comment: Nice! what do```summarise``` and ```pull``` do?

Answer (score 7):

`.data$x` does not refer to a column whose name is held in a variable `x` but refers to a column called `"x"`. Use `.data[[x]]` to refer to the column whose name is the character string held in variable `x` and call your function using  character string `"mpg"`.

```
library(magrittr)
custom_function <- function(.data, x) mean(.data[[x]])

mtcars %>% custom_function("mpg")
## [1] 20.09062
```